# how to translate html file contents into another language?

Tags: python, html, css, formatting, translation

On using the below code I was not getting the exact formatting as I got before translating.
Please guide me where I am making mistakes.

Code

```
from googletrans import Translator
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag,NavigableString
html = open("data.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup.find_all(["p","ul","ol","h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6","td"])
translator=Translator()
def callcon(t, tag):
  for i in range(0, len(t)):
    if type(t[i])== NavigableString:
      #print(t[i])
      translation=translator.translate(t[i],dest="hi").text
      new_text = tag.find(text=str(t[i])).replace_with(translation)
      #print(new_text)
      #og=og.replace(str(t[i]),"suneri")
      #return og
    else:
      #print(t[i].contents)
      #print(og)
      callcon(t[i].contents,tag)
for tag in tags:
  #constr="".join(str(e) for e in tag.contents)
  #print(constr)
  callcon(tag.contents, tag)
with open("output2.html", "wb") as f_output:
    f_output.write(soup.prettify("utf-8"))
```

Comment: `"I was not getting the exact formatting as I got before translating"` - so what does that mean? What's different after your text is translated?

Comment: Basically margin shifting, all text getting patched up one upon another etc. I am doing this because I want to convert pdf to html and then translate and then again html to pdf. Thus translating the pdf with formatting  but after translating the formatting is changing.

Comment: This sounds more like CSS issues because you're likely causing elements to reflow/overflow/whatever because your translated text is not all going to be as long as the original one. You're going to have to create your own CSS or customize the pre-existing CSS you can get from the scraped page to support the post-translation layout.

Answer (score 2):

```
text_elements = [element for element in soup.find_all(string=True) if element.parent.name not in ['script', 'style']]

for element in text_elements:
    # Extract the text from the element
    text = element.get_text(strip=True)
    # Skip the element if it's empty
    if not text:
        continue
    # Translate the text
    translated_text = translator.translate(text, dest='hi')
    # Replace the text in the element
    element.replace_with(translated_text)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).